# How to gracefully terminate python process on windows

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I have a python 2.7 process running in the background on Windows 8.1.

Is there a way to gracefully terminate this process and perform cleanup on shutdown or log off?

Comment: Set up an IPC communication channel and request that the Python program terminates via that channel

Comment: might be somewhat related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216788/win32-api-analog-of-sending-catching-sigterm

Comment: Your issue sounds slightly different than mine, although they seem to be in the same ballpark. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199817/stopping-a-python-process-so-that-context-managers-still-call-exit-in-windo

Answer (score 2):

Try using win32api.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent.

I solved this for a multiprocessing python program here:
[Gracefully Terminate Child Python Process On Windows so Finally clauses run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731434/gracefully-terminate-child-python-process-on-windows-so-finally-clauses-run/46530764#46530764)

I tested this solution using subprocess.Popen, and it also works.

Here is a code example:

```
import time
import win32api
import win32con
from multiprocessing import Process


def foo():
    try:
        while True:
            print("Child process still working...")
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Child process: caught ctrl-c"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(2)

    print "sending ctrl c..."
    try:
        win32api.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(win32con.CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)
        while p.is_alive():
            print("Child process is still alive.")
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Main process: caught ctrl-c"
```